# How to delete a specific <td> cell with no id from a dynamically added table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

The table involves a dropdown box and a normal `<td>` with a value. When `onChange` of the dropdown, the specific `<td>` must change to another dropdown. I've used jQuery to implement the function, but while I change the dropdown for the first row, the change is happening for the entire table. I just need the change to happen for the single row where the `onChange` function has been called.

```
$('td:nth-child(11),th:nth-child(11)').hide();
$('td:nth-child(10),th:nth-child(10)').show();
```

is used to hide and show the 10th and 11th columns.

doc.ready function() :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td:nth-child(11),th:nth-child(11)').show();
  $('td:nth-child(10),th:nth-child(10)').hide();
  // ...
```

onChange function used :

```
$(document).on('change','.mySelect', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $('td:nth-child(11),th:nth-child(11)').hide();
  $('td:nth-child(10),th:nth-child(10)').show();
  //$(this).closest("td").show();

  var _this = $(this);
  var id =_this.val();
  var statusValue = id;

  $.get('AssignedTo', { statusVal : statusValue }, function(response) {
    var select = _this.closest("tr").find("select[name='assigned']");
    /* var select = $('#assigned'); */
    select.find('option').remove();

    $.each(response, function(index, value) {
      $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: If you're trying to get the `<tr>` that the `<select>` is in, you can select it with jQuery by using `$(this).closest("tr");` in the `change` event. `closest()` will return the nearest ancestor that matches the given selector, so in your case, it will match the nearest parent/grandparent/etc that is a `<tr>`.

Comment: that will just find the row, I need to get to a specific <td> inside that row. @Santi

Comment: try `$(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(11),th:nth-child(11)')` - that is the closest tr of the changed select and then find the tds in that row

Comment: @Pete I'm getting a syntax error for that `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child
    at Function.fa.error`

Comment: You're much better off using `.eq()` in jQuery instead of `nth-child`. Try something like `$(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(10);` or `$(this).closest('td').siblings('td').addBack().eq(10);` - [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rpm7upqn/1/)

Comment: or instead of that selector for th and td, as santi said you can just do eq on the children`$(this).closest('tr').children().eq(10)` - eq is 0 based index so 10 is 11th child

Comment: I think they're working, but the show() hide() part isn't working. when I'm using `$(this).closest('td').siblings('td').addBack().eq(10);` as @Santi said, the `hide()` part is working, but the other dropdown isn't showing.

Comment: You should really include your HTML. Examples on Stack are generally required to be Complete and Verifiable, but with only jQuery, your question is neither. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) We're all pretty much just grasping at straws here without seeing what we're even trying to select, etc.

Comment: Wooorked!! Thanks @Pete and  Santi It worked. The numbers I got wrong I presume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `nth-child`, consider using `eq()` - it's cleaner and doesn't come with some of the specificity issues of `nth-child`.

- To get all `<td>` elements in the "changed" row, you can get the parent`<td>` by doing `.closest("td")` and select all of its siblings using `.siblings("td")`
- To include the original one (and not *only* siblings), you'd use `.addBack()`.
- Finally, now that we have all the cells in the row, select the one you want using `eq()`.

Put all together, it looks like this:

```
//Select the 11th cell in the row
var $cell = $(this).closest('td').siblings('td').addBack().eq(10);
```

Or, you could get the parent and choose all its children (instead of siblings) using `.closest("tr")` and `children()`:

```
//Select the 11th cell in the row
var $cell = $(this).closest("tr").children("td").eq(10);
```